# How to think about a database design when users have different amounts of input

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to conceptualize a simple application just for me and my friends to record our workouts on. I can't seem to grasp my head around how to model the data. Each User can input a Workout. A Workout has 1 or more exercises. Each exercise has 1 or more set. Each set has at least 1 rep & weight. The best I've been able to come up with is the below.|

```
Workout Table       
1   User_A  9-Jul   
2   User_B  9-Jul   
3   User_C  9-Jul   
4   User_A  10-Jul  
5   User_D  10-Jul  
6   User_B  11-Jul

Exercise Table
1   Bench       3 reps  135 lbs Workout_1
2   Bench       3 reps  185 lbs Workout_1
3   Deadlift    5 reps  225 lbs Workout_2
```

Am I on the right track here? This will be my first time making any app that isn't a blog tutorial. This seems like that Exercise Table would get very large very fast. Perhaps thats normal though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right track and you could probably add `Users` Table and change your `Workout` Table to `UsersWorkout` Table and create a relationship between the two. And then you could probably change your Exercise table to `WorkoutExercise` Table and create a separate Table for `Exercise` that has the type of Exercises (e.g. *Bench, Deadlift*).

See my attached **ERD** below from `MS Access`:

[image]

And below are Sample Data for each table:

**Users**

[image: Users]

**User's Workouts**

[image: UserWorkout]

**Workout's Exercises**

[image: WorkoutExercise]

And finally **Exercises**

[image: Exercises]

These are [Normalized](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/) tables by the way to prevent redundancy and prevent UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT anomalies.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I left off the Users table since I understood that side. It was the rest I was not confident on. Why does it make more sense to put the Exercises in their own table, seems unnecessary to me? On the Normalized and most examples I find it makes sense since it would be like ItemID, ItemName, ItemCostPerUnit but is really faster to have its own table just to change from name to id?

Comment: On Exercise table yes you could put it on WorkoutExercise table. However, there is a danger of update anomaly which what Normalized tables would supposedly do. For example let's say you want to change the Exercise Type from Deadlift to Dead-Lift (I know I'm wrong but this is only for the sake of example). And let's say further that you have already 1 million records in your Workout Exercise table. So, that means you have to update 1M records just for that. Now, contrast if you have a table for Exercise, you only update one record!

Comment: Additionally what if you have a user who type it as Deedlift or Deadlifts so you will have there an inconsistent records however again if you have the table for Example that would not be a problem. Now, I am not saying you could not de-normalized but what I am trying to say there is also a trade-off in that design.